# Embedding pig query in JAVA files for operation

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

i am looking for embedding the pig query in java map-reduce program. I want to know that whether it is possible or not.
If possible how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by [reading the documentation on "embeded pig"](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/cont.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. Take a look at the documentation @Arnon suggested. Basically it is using PigServer to register your query/jar. You could use control flow construct to chain jobs thereafter.